# Onbeforeunload doesn't work until mouse is clicked once in the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, onbeforeunload

After a long day of trying to find a solution to this problem, I keep getting the same issue.

Basically, I have a site, if the user clicks on the "browser-refresh" button, I want to pop-up a "are you sure" alert box with the options "reload" and "don't reload" (Basically, what the browser returns).

Surprisingly, it works just fine in IE. But in chrome or firefox, the refresh happens normally without a popup.

The popup only appears if I click on the body some where and then click on the "browser-refresh" button.

I already the following and other many similar alternatives :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

   // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
   if (e) {
       e.returnValue = 'Any string';
   }

  // For Safari
  return 'Any string';
};
```

I tried to simulate a click event on page load with 'trigger('click')', '.click()' events.

But, still doesn't work until I click on the body myself (physically).

I've created a short pen, which replicates the issue I'm facing.

https://codepen.io/kanchanrai/pen/LQEZYV

Any help would be very highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why would you need to do this in the first place? It's just annoying to users if there is no interaction with page and no valid reason to need to warn user

Comment: This was just an example and pointing out the exact issue. I saw these kinds of replies on almost all questions asked. This is required for a payment page that I'm working on a project. I can't elaborate more than that but just this, there's a valid reason the user needs to be warned. 
I'm all done except for that one part where the body needs to be clicked.

Comment: Since Chrome 60: [Require user gesture for beforeunload dialogs](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5082396709879808)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a late answer...

Here is what [MDN documentation on beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) states:

> Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with, or may even not display them at all.

This matches the behavior you observed.

Comment: Yes agreed, after attempting several methods, an actual click was mandatory somehow. So, we opted for an alternative solution from Backend instead! Thanks for the response felix.

Comment: @KanchanRai what was the final solution you came up with?